# Append proxy once httpclient is created

Tags: go

In my application already the HTTP Client is already present with certificate loaded, I want to check with given proxy if my backend is reachable or not, I don't want to create new httpClient but want to append proxy details to given HTTP Client.

```
func HTTPClient(proxyRequest models.ProxyRequest) (*http.Client, error) {
configPath, _ := dcsutils.GetConfig(connectivityconstants.CONNECTIVITY_HOME)
certFile, certReaderr := ioutil.ReadFile(filepath.Join(configPath, connectivityconstants.CONFIG_PATH_STR, connectivityconstants.BOOTSTRAP_KEYSTORE))
if certReaderr != nil {
    fmt.Println(certReaderr)
}
pkey3, cert5, _, err5 := pkcs12.DecodeChain(certFile, "passoword")
if err5 != nil {

}
cert := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE", Bytes: cert5.Raw})
privateKey := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(pkey3.(*rsa.PrivateKey))})
clientCAs := x509.NewCertPool()
clientCAs.AppendCertsFromPEM(certFile)
certificate, certCreateErr := tls.X509KeyPair(cert, privateKey)
if certCreateErr != nil {
    fmt.Println(certCreateErr)
}
HttpPreRegistrationClientVar := &http.Client{}
HttpPreRegistrationClientVar.Transport = &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{certificate},
        ClientCAs:          clientCAs,
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    },
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(&url.URL{
        User: url.UserPassword(proxyRequest.UserName, proxyRequest.Password),
        Host: proxyRequest.ServerAddress + ":" + proxyRequest.PortNumber,
    }),
}

return HttpPreRegistrationClientVar, nil
```

The above client I have modified to add proxy, but that's not what i want I want to append the proxy later once httpclient got created.

```
Proxy: http.ProxyURL(&url.URL{
        User: url.UserPassword(proxyRequest.UserName, proxyRequest.Password),
        Host: proxyRequest.ServerAddress + ":" + proxyRequest.PortNumber,
    })
```

Comment: Do you have some code to share ?

Comment: Create a single client (`cli := &http.Client{}`) and use this to submit http requests to multiple destinations.

Comment: @colm.anseo that I have already there Can I create append the new changes in Tranport once it is intialized?

Answer (score 0):

From the [http.Client](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) docs:

> Clients are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

and

> A Client is higher-level than a RoundTripper (such as Transport) and additionally handles HTTP details such as cookies and redirects.

Changing the `Transport` of a client *directly* while it was being used would cause a data-race.

*However*, you could implement your own `Transport` via the `RoundTripper` interface [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43448702/1218512) - but one should be careful to put synchronized locking around the transport and if it changes - to avoid any data-race conditions if the client is being used concurrently.

One such implementation:

```
type DynRoundTripper struct {
    l  sync.Mutex
    rt http.RoundTripper
}

func NewDynRoundTripper(rt http.RoundTripper) *DynRoundTripper {
    if rt == nil {
        rt = http.DefaultTransport
    }
    return &DynRoundTripper{
        rt: rt,
    }
}

func (d *DynRoundTripper) RoundTrip(r *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    d.l.Lock()
    rt := d.rt
    d.l.Unlock() // unlock now, as rt.RoundTrip may take a while...

    return rt.RoundTrip(r)
}


cli := &http.Client{
    Transport: NewDynRoundTripper(nil), // default http transport
}
```

and to change the transport:

```
// var cli            *http.Client
// var proxyTransport *http.Transport

cli.Transport.(*DynRoundTripper).Set(proxyTransport)


func (d *DynRoundTripper) Set(rt http.RoundTripper) {
    d.l.Lock()
    defer d.l.Unlock()
    d.rt = rt
}
```

Comment: If I got it correct it will override existing transport but will not append the property in existing transport?

Comment: You could easily tailor this to instead of replacing the whole `http.RoundTripper` to just set the `Proxy` field of an existing `*http.Transport`